# Window.onblur function not working in Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome:

```
    window.onblur = () => {
      console.log('blur')
    }
```

I ran that code in Firefox and it worked, then ran the same code in Chrome, and it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/at6c0kL7

Chrome: Version 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: this is strange.. it works fine for me on chrome

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? I'm trying it in Chrome, Chrome Canary and also Firefox and it works well

Comment: Checked on Linux and Windows. Same here. It's working.

Comment: Well, same, do you have Logs turned on in the Inspector?

Comment: @DominikMatis ya. I just added a "foo" log and could see it.

Comment: How are you running it ? Just writing in inspector? Or some JS file loaded to html

Comment: @DominikMatis Don't entirely know what you mean by "writing in inspector", but in the fiddle I just have the JS code, and open up the dev tools console to view the logs. The "foo" logs, but not "blur" when I click on another window or browser tab.

Comment: oh, if you are trying it only in fiddle, then you will see it on the right side at the bottom

Comment: It won't be visible in your browser console

Comment: @DominikMatis Oh cool, didn't know that! Though, the "blur" log is still not showing, though "foo" is ("foo" does show in the browser console btw). The mind boggles.

Comment: You should see at least a number 1 next to icon with an exclamation mark in circle, you can click on it to see it

Comment: @DominikMatis drats, I wasn't testing properly. I started seeing "blur" in the console after clicking on the HTML part of the fiddle, then clicking off of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ES5 instead on ES6 syntax, like so:

```js
 window.onblur = function(){
      console.log('blur')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be working for me either.

You can try this instead:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    console.log('Hidden');
  }
});
```

Works with Chrome: Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (x86_64)